# Can't restore iPhone in order to downgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, restore, downgrade

I just downloaded the iOS 11 beta from Apple's developer website, but I'm having such a headache downgrading back to iOS 10.3.2.

I installed their provisioning profile from their website, as instructed on their site.

**To restore, I did the following:**

I restarted my iPhone to recovery mode to restore it, only to be presented this message:

> the iPhone could not be updated. Declined to authorize this image on this device for this user

I rebooted it to find the provisioning profile in order to delete it, only to find that the management page in settings was not there and neither Xcode/Devices nor Apple Configurator 2 showed any profiles.

Now I'm stuck on iOS 11, and I can't figure out how to downgrade.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I might have idea but that’s risky - you need to JB your iphone, then use official JB uninstaller (this one in cydia) - it automatically makes factory reset and bypasses even configuration profiles (it just deletes all user’s files - settings, apps, etc. , same as factory reset) .